# htlatex: extra row at end of table

Tags: tables, htlatex, accessibility

I'm using `htlatex` to produce HTML that is designed to be read with assistive technology.

In the following minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here is a table with 2 rows and 2 columns:
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I run the following command

```
htlatex.exe tmp.tex
```

Then among the output in `tmp.html` is the following

```
<table id="TBL-1" class="tabular" cellspacing="0"
        cellpadding="0">
          <colgroup id="TBL-1-1g">
            <col id="TBL-1-1">
            <col id="TBL-1-2">
          </colgroup>
          <tr style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-">
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id=
            "TBL-1-1-1" class="td11">1</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id=
            "TBL-1-1-2" class="td11">2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-2-">
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id=
            "TBL-1-2-1" class="td11">3</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id=
            "TBL-1-2-2" class="td11">4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-3-">
            <td style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id=
            "TBL-1-3-1" class="td11"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

The **most important** part of the output above is the final *empty* row. There are two reasons I would like to remove this:

1. when read with a screen reader, I am told that the above table has 3 rows and 2 columns; this is not correct, and it forces me to navigate past an empty row unnecessarily
2. when validated with `nu html validator` (https://github.com/validator/validator) I am told that, among other things:

> error: A table row was 1 columns wide, which is less than the column count established using column markup (2)

### Work around

I can use some `perl` to remove this final row, but I'd prefer to have a native solution.

### The question

How can I configure `htlatex` so that a final, empty row is not added to the `html` output of a `tabular` environment?

Comment: `perl -p0i.bak -e 's/<tr[^>]*>(\R|\h)*<td[^>]*><\/td>(\h|\R)*<\/tr>(\h|\R)*<\/table>/<\/table>/sg tmp.html` seems to remove the final blank row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. You can either leave the last `\\` command, or use the `make4ht` filter. I don't think `tex4ht` can be configured to detect empty rows.

The filter can look like this:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter{
  function(dom)
    for _, row in ipairs(dom:query_selector("tr")) do
      -- get row contents, strip all whitespace
      local text = row:get_text():gsub("%s*", "")
      -- remove empty nodes
      if text == "" then
        print "empty row"
        row:remove_node()
      end
    end
    return dom
  end
}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

It is longer than perl script, but hopefully more readable. It can be required using the `-e` option, or automatically when it has the same name as the TeX file, just with `mk4` extension.

```
make4ht -e buildfilename.mk4 tmp.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks optimistic. Could you provide the explicit call to the `mk4ht` command?

Comment: @cmhughes sure. it is `make4ht`, not `mk4ht`, there is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: That's great many thanks. It seems like we either need to *pre* process the `.tex` file, or otherwise *post* process the `.html` file

Comment: @cmhughes yes, in such case it is probably better to post-process the `.html` file

Comment: Thanks a lot for this; when I run my `html` files through this filter, all of the `"` (double quotes) are replaced with `'` (single quotes)... is this expected? can it be customized/changed so that I keep the double quotes? or perhaps single quotes are preferable?

Comment: @cmhughes yes, LuaXML serializes XML with single quotes. It is not configurable unfortunately, but it should take care of character escaping, so it shouldn't  cause issues. I don't remember why I choose single quotes, but I guess it had some practical reason.